# Passing error from Nodejs but not receiving the right one

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, promise, react-redux

Here is my code where I am getting the upload video and checking it extension when extention is not mp4 i want to return else statement and pass the the error from server but when i am getting this error and when i am console.log this error this print the server not responding 505 error it is working fine with when extention is mp4.

```
const videoStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, config.videoStorage);
  },
  filename: function (req, videoFile, cb) {
    if (path.extension(videoFile.originalname) !== '.mp4') {
      const name = `${videoFile
        .fieldname}-${Date
        .now()}_${
      videoFile.originalname}`;
      return cb(null, name.replace(/\s/g, ""));
    } else {
      return cb(new Error("sorry"));
    }
  }
});

MediaService
  .uploadVideo(formData, this.getUploadProgress)
  .then(data => {
    let order = {
      ...this.state.project
    };
    if (!order.project) {
      order = {
        project: {
          mediaId: data
        }
      };
    }
    order.project.mediaId = data;
    console.log("videoid added ===", order);
    this.setState({uploading: false, videoId: data, isValid: true, project: order});

    message.success("Video uploaded successfully");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    message.error(error);
    this.setState({message: error, uploading: false});
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing error,you can pass flag like this:

```
return cb({success:false,message:"false"});
```

This you can access in success promise of uploader.

Because when you are saying `new Error()`, i think it will throw an error on server side and it will not be able to send response to client.that is why you are not getting response on client side.